# Celery dies after a few hours

Tags: python, celery

Since moving to docker, celery seems to stop accepting tasks.

In the process list are lots of these:

`www-data 29039  0.0  0.6 287428 71260 ?        S    05:19   0:00 /usr/bin/python -c from billiard.forking import main; main() --billiard-fork 43`

(about 200)

I am on the latest celery and billiard. Celery settings look like this:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 3600

CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Etc/UTC'
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = True

CELERYD_FORCE_EXECV = True
```

Thanks